# Is it possible to automatically pull new versions of a docker image and deploy them on a Raspberry pi?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, docker-image, cicd, gitops

I am running docker containers on a Raspberry pi. I miss the last puzzle of my CI/CD project that is to automate the flow (pull the newest docker images from my repo and deploy it) and was wondering if someone else had figured this process out? Is there an existing script or a polling-service/ listener that waits for changes in my docker repo? I have tried to search around for solutions or hints on how to get this to work but my attempts have so far been unsuccessful.

Every hint/tips/links is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know its been 4 months, but this might be what you're looking for: https://fluxcd.io/docs/guides/image-update/

It will check the hub at specified intervals and retrieve the latest tags, and you can also set it up to automatically update your deployments.

Good luck :)

Comment: Please list the steps here.  Links can disappear, so they are not encouraged as an answer.  They should be used to supplement your answer.